# How to know activity has been finished?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to check to see if an activity is running or finished. Is there any method through which I can check the status of activity?

I found `activity.isFinishing()` but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Can you say exactly what you want to do in your project so i can get some clear idea to solve your query..

Comment: running can take all matters of form, so i would be best know your purpose here.

Comment: some times we get window token error because activity get finish and dialog box still called so before calling dialog i want to check whether activity is running or not.

Comment: @ConnectinglifewithAndroid How did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Using activity.isFinishing() is the right one solution. it return true if activity is finished so before creating dialog check for the condition. if true then create and show dialog.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to perform any step before `Activity` is going to become invisible.

Their are several choices here.

[onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) - for final cleanup.

[isFinishing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29) - right after `act.finish()` is called it will return true.

[onStop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) - when the `Activity` is killed by framework process. (not destroyed)

[onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) - when the `Activity` is covered by any other `Activity`

[onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) - capturing the event of hardware Back key triggered by user.

Comment: There is also `isDestoyed()` (added in API 17) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29

Comment: Yes, it was released later, so that's why its not included in the answer. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: I think the expression 'killed' can cause some confusion. For example, `onStop()` is called when another application comes to the foreground. But the Activity's state is maintained, so it's not killed :)

Answer (score 6):

Call isFinishing in the onPause method before the activity is destroyed:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        // Here  you can be sure the Activity will be destroyed eventually
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very old, but for anyone using Kotlin:

We can check within a Fragment:

```
// FRAGMENT
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    // Log.v(TAG, "onPause");
    if(requireActivity().isChangingConfigurations) {
         // Config change
    } else {
        if(requireActivity().isFinishing) {
            // deal with activity ending (finish up viewModel etc)
        }
        // deal with rotate or other config changes as required
    }
}
```

Of course, we can also just do this directly inside an activity (just remove the requireActivity() parts).